# How does vector's growth function work?

Tags: c++, c++14, stdvector

```
int main () {
    std::vector <int> elements;
    elements.push_back (1);
    elements [10000] = 102;
    std:: cout << elements [10000];
    return 0;
}
```

How does the above code work? As far as I have read, vector's growth will be 1.5 - 2x. So how is the 10000th element stored here? Isn't the expected behavior here a "Segmentation fault"? But the above runs successfully.

Comment: The subscript operator have never had bounds checking, and indexing out of bounds have always been *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The behaviour is undefined; there is no expected behaviour.

Comment: @molbdnilo unexpected and undefined are different things

Comment: Whoever downvotes a question should say why and help. If a user cannot leave any comments before downvoting I suggest skipping the down vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So how is the 10000th element stored here?

The element *isn't* stored in the vector. It's 'stored' in a piece of memory that is unrelated to the vector.

> Isn't the expected behavior here a "Segmentation fault"?

No. The behaviour is undefined, so there is no behaviour to expect.

> But the above runs successfully.

That's a possible behaviour when the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

the fact that you see that something is working, does not mean that it is legal, or should work.
In this case, as mentioned in the comments, you do read out of bounds.
In your case, you were luck (or, actually, unlucky), and all worked fine for you.
this may not be the case in other cases. you may step on someone else's memory, for example.

you can run this under valgrind, and see the errors:

> ==31899== Invalid write of size 4
>   ==31899==    at 0x400B30: main (in a.out)
>   ==31899==  Address 0x5a21c80 is 39,920 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 4,194,128 in arena "client"
>   ==31899==
>   ==31899== Invalid read of size 4
>   ==31899==    at 0x400B47: main (in a.out)
>   ==31899==  Address 0x5a21c80 is 39,920 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 4,194,128 in arena "clien
>
> t"
>   ==31899==

you can also try and use `.at()` instead of `[]`.
In this case you out_of_range exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Generally small out of bounds reads will not generate a segfault as you will be reading from memory which is already allocated to your process.

Segfaults only occur when you try to read or write from an address which isn't currently allocated to your application. Out of bounds writes will generally lead to segfaults more quickly by overwriting vital control information causing future memory accesses to be out of bounds.

C++ itself (usually) does no bounds checking for raw memory accesses, the segfaults are generated by the OS which knows nothing about the memory structure of your application.